# How to prevent screenshots from undoing the hidden status bar?

Tags: android, user-interface, fullscreen, statusbar

I am using the method found in the [Android doc](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status#41)

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

I am also using this flag to re-hide the status bar when the user swipes down the status bar. Without this flag, one swipe will unhide the status bar.

```
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
```

However, taking a screenshot of the screen will unhide the status bar. Which flag or method can I use to prevent screenshots from permanently revealing the status bar?

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial fix. It is not perfect but my solution is to re-hide the status bar onWindowFocusChanged().

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    // <Insert code here to re-hide status bar>
}
```

However, this shows animation artifacts because we are actively hiding and unhiding the status bar whenever the window focus changes. I tried taking a screenshot with some calculator apps without a status bar, and there is no animation involved.

However, for my app, you will see the status bar hide and unhide while taking a screenshot and returning to the app window.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution without the animation?